# How to rotate gray scale image easily

Tags: css

I am applying two equations of rotation to rotate gray scale images easily. It's not rotating, however.

The two equations are:

```
x' = x *cos (theta) - y *sin (theta)
```

and

```
y' = x *sin (theta) + y *cos (theta)
```

I have visited a number of Q&A's on this site but the explanations are unclear.

```
IMG imgRotate(IMG output, float deg)
{

  IMG lalo;
  lalo.degree = deg;


  float radian = ((2 *pi*output.degree) / 360);

  float cosine = cos(radian);
  float sine = sin(radian);
  int x1 = (output.height * sine);
  int y1 = (output.height * cosine);
  int x2 = (output.width * cosine + output.height* sine);
  int y2 = (output.height* cosine -output.width * sine);
  int x3 = (output.width * cosine);
  int y3 =(-output.width * sine);
  int minx = min(0, min(x1, min(x2, x3)));
  int miny = min(0, min(y1, min(y2, y3)));
  int maxx = max(0, max(x1, max(x2, x3)));
  int maxy = max(0, max(y1, max(y2, y3)));

  int w = maxx - minx;
  int h = maxy - miny;
  int x, y,nx,ny;


  lalo.pixel = (unsigned char*)calloc(lalo.height*lalo.width, sizeof (unsigned char));

    for (y = 0; y < h; y++)
    {
        for (x = 0; x <w; x++)
        {
            nx = ceilf(x*cos(radian) - y*sin(radian));
            ny = ceilf(x*sin(radian) + y*cos(radian));

            lalo.pixel[w*ny + nx] = output.pixel[w*ny + nx];
        }
    }
    return lalo;

}
```

I have added the following code but it is giving incomplete image

```
IMG imgRotate(IMG output,float deg, int height, int width)
{

  IMG lalo;
  lalo.degree = deg;
  lalo.width = width;
  lalo.height = height;
  lalo.pixel=(unsigned char*)calloc (lalo.height*lalo.width, sizeof (unsigned char));

  float radian = ((2 *pi*lalo.degree) / 360);
  int x, y, x1, y1;

  for (y = 0; y < lalo.height; y++)
  {
    for (x = 0; x <lalo.width; x++)
    {
      x1 = ceilf(x*cos(radian)-y*sin(radian));
      y1 = ceilf(x*sin(radian) + y*cos(radian));
      lalo.pixel[lalo.width*y1+x1] = output.pixel[output.width*x1+y1];
    }
  }
  return lalo;
}
```

Comment: Your question does not seem related to CSS. Please clarify what program you are using and what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

this is the we do with `css` it may help not sure

```css
.image-class {
   
    /* Rotate div */
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<img class="image-class" src="https://media-mediatemple.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/images/behavioral-css/transform_rotate.png"/>
```

Comment: dear please diagnose my code..and tell me accordingly

Comment: @raja, you should be more than able to piece it together given this information. These rules are how you rotate an image using CSS in all three of the major browser types.

Comment: why nobody is helping me..?,,,

Comment: when i say i have two arrays ..one input ,other output..i am applying now below code ..but that is not operating..i have been trying for last two days..please help me.. ' void imgCopy(IMG input, IMG output)
{
 int i, j, degree, newx, newy;
 degree=90;
 float radian = (( degree*pi) / 180);
 for (i = 0; i < output.height; i++)
 {
  for (j = 0; j < output.width; j++)
  {
   newx = ceilf(j*cos(radian) - i*sin(radian));
   newy = ceilf(j*sin(radian) + i*cos(radian));
   output.pixel[output.width*newx + newy] = input.pixel[input.width*newx + newy];
  }
 
 }

}   '